# How To Create List In Android

Tags: android

I want to create list in android as shown in figure. can anyone help me please.

[image]

the problem is that i can't understand how to create this type of listview for nested items. like in this figure limes don't have nested element so it contains checkbox on the other hand melons contains nested elements so it contains arrow to view nested items.

edit: Can an expendable Listview and a normal Listview be combined;

Comment: what's the problem? what have you tried?

Comment: the problem is that i can't understand how to create this type of listview for nested items. like in this figure limes don't have nested element so it contains checkbox on the other hand melons contains nested elements so it contains arrow to view nested items.

Comment: Look at http://androidsourcecodemj.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-use-expandable-list-in-android.html

Answer (score 3):

To create a list like the one in the picture you will have to use a [listview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

There are plenty of tutorials for this, here are a couple:

- http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: try https://github.com/draxdave/ConstraintAccordion